# How to retrieve grid item data from arrayList in android

Tags: android, gridview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am fetching data from json and saving into arrayList of custom class type. Here it is,

```
class ShowInfo{
    public String title;
    public String image;
    public String id;
}
ArrayList<ShowInfo> imgs = new ArrayList<ShowInfo>();
```

My gridView adapter class is -

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShowInfo> {

    CustomAdapter() {
        super(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, imgs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_image, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(imgs.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }
}
class ViewHolder{
    // public TextView payment = null;
    public ImageView image = null;

    ViewHolder(View view){
        image = new RoundedImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width / rowLimit, width / rowLimit);
        params2.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);

        //content.setLayoutParams(params);

    }

    void populateFrom(GalleryInfo info){

        // image.setImageBitmap(info.logo);
        Picasso.with(getActivity())
                .load(info.image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.dittyicon)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .into(image);
    }
}
```

When click on any item of gridview I want to get title and id of corresponding grid image. I could I get that?
I am stuck here, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `OnItemClickListener` you can do it as follows

```
yourGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            ShowInfo info=imgs.get(position);
            //By using info you can get title and id
        }
    });
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

on your onItemClick() you can 
    `imgs.get(position).getImageid();
    imgs.get(position).getImageTitle();`